# HTML5 Canvas Grid not rendering

Tags: html, canvas, grid

This question is extremely rudimentary but I'm just starting out with "HTML5 Up and Running" and can't seem to get my canvas grid to render. Below is the code. Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Canvas | HTML5</title>
<style type="text/css">
#c {border:1px solid #000;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">


function draw_grid() {
    var c_canvas = document.getElementById("c");
    var context = c_canvas.getContext("2d");

    for (var x = 0.5; x < 500; x += 10) {
    context.moveTo(x, 0);
    context.lineTo(x, 375);
    }

    for (var y = 0.5; y < 375; y += 10) {
    context.moveTo(0, y);
    context.lineTo(500, y);
    }

    context.strokeStyle = "#eee";
    context.stroke();
}
draw_grid();


</script>

</head>

<body>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="225"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

your HTML is not ready when you JS gets executed...

Put you script tag after the canvas, and it should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/vQE3f/1/

In your code when JS is executing `document.getElementById("c");` the browser don't know that there is a canvas with a id C,,,

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `window.onload = draw_grid;` or (when you have more code) `window.onload = function(){ ...do stuff with the page... };`

Answer (score 1):

I just launched a project on GitHub for this issue. It's called [grid.js](http://enterprisebug.github.com/grid.js/).

You do not have to worry about drawing a grid. Maybe you will give it a try.